# NSRangeException exception on NSMutableArray

Tags: iphone, xcode, nsmutablearray

I am getting the following error please help me with a solution. My xcode gets aborted with the following error

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[NSMutableArray objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty array'
*** Call stack at first throw:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x0140a5a9 __exceptionPreprocess + 185
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0155e313 objc_exception_throw + 44
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x014000a5 -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:] + 261
    3   UMMCelebrity                        0x00043903 -[UMMFlickrView photoGallery:urlForPhotoSize:atIndex:] + 115
    4   UMMCelebrity                        0x0004a9d6 -[FGalleryViewController createGalleryPhotoForIndex:] + 422
    5   UMMCelebrity                        0x0004a5ac -[FGalleryViewController loadThumbnailImageWithIndex:] + 172
    6   UMMCelebrity                        0x0004a189 -[FGalleryViewController preloadThumbnailImages] + 281
    7   UMMCelebrity                        0x00046f84 -[FGalleryViewController loadView] + 2132
    8   UIKit                               0x0029d00e -[UIViewController view] + 56
    9   UMMCelebrity                        0x00043050 -[UMMFlickrView pushphotoview] + 192
    10  UMMCelebrity                        0x000446c6 -[UMMFlickrView connection:didReceiveData:] + 2230
    11  Foundation                          0x00996835 _NSURLConnectionDidReceiveData + 159
    12  CFNetwork                           0x033bde72 _ZN19URLConnectionClient21_clientDidReceiveDataEPK8__CFDataPNS_26ClientConnectionEventQueueE + 262
    13  CFNetwork                           0x0348a6b3 _ZN19URLConnectionClient26ClientConnectionEventQueue33processAllEventsAndConsumePayloadEP20XConnectionEventInfoI12XClientEvent18XClientEventParamsEl + 247
    14  CFNetwork                           0x0348a9cf _ZN19URLConnectionClient26ClientConnectionEventQueue33processAllEventsAndConsumePayloadEP20XConnectionEventInfoI12XClientEvent18XClientEventParamsEl + 1043
    15  CFNetwork                           0x033b5c80 _ZN19URLConnectionClient13processEventsEv + 100
    16  CFNetwork                           0x033b5acf _ZN17MultiplexerSource7performEv + 251
    17  CoreFoundation                      0x013eb8ff __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 15
    18  CoreFoundation                      0x0134988b __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 571
    19  CoreFoundation                      0x01348d86 __CFRunLoopRun + 470
    20  CoreFoundation                      0x01348840 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 208
    21  CoreFoundation                      0x01348761 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 97
    22  GraphicsServices                    0x018e21c4 GSEventRunModal + 217
    23  GraphicsServices                    0x018e2289 GSEventRun + 115
    24  UIKit                               0x001fbc93 UIApplicationMain + 1160
    25  UMMCelebrity                        0x00001d29 main + 121
    26  UMMCelebrity                        0x00001ca5 start + 53
)
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'NSException'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're calling `objectAtIndex:` with the argument `0` on an empty `NSMutableArray`.

```
[NSMutableArray objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty array
```

If you know the `NSMutableArray` can be empty, you should consider calling [`count`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSArray/count) on it to see if it does indeed contain any elements, before trying to access the elements.

Comment: NSMutableArray is not empty.Its getting filled through a url (it contains images on button click) but the 4th button click aborts the code. Can u suggest me the solution?

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, there's an empty `NSMutableArray` in `-[UMMFlickrView photoGallery:urlForPhotoSize:atIndex:]` and you sent it `objectAtIndex:` with argument 0.

Comment: url=[networkImages_w objectAtIndex:index]; I am getting aborted at this point. can u please tell me what should i put here?

Answer (score 0):

That means your NSMutableArray is empty. I think you didn't allocate the memory for NSMutableArray. Read this link, it may be helpful for you.
http://www.roseindia.net/answers/viewqa/Mobile-Applications/14614-NSMutableArray-Example-Code.html

Comment: If the memory wasn't allocated, the error would be completely different.

Comment: memory is allocated for the array. array is getting filled 3 times (3 button clicks are working properly and gets exited on 4th click)

Answer (score 0):

May be on the 4th click nothing is pushed into the array, I'm not sure as I have no idea what you are trying to do.If you can add the code line that adds the object into your array, we could help you.

This error is occurring because the array is empty for sure.